# running mongoDB in a web hosting

Tags: mongodb, web-hosting

Is there any way to run the mongoDB in goddady or any other hosting websites except for mongoHQ and so on?
and if I use mongoHQ , is that safe for the data and fast ?
I'm right now using it in the localhost server as a windows service .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to run software like MongoDB in a web environment, you'll need a [Virtual Private Server (VPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). This is like having an entire machine that you can install anything on and do anything with. The downside is that you have to install and configure all the software on it, including backups and disaster recovery, which a shared host will usually do for you instead. The upside is that you have more system resources, so you can do more, and you can install any software you want, so you have more flexibility. My personal recommendation is [Linode](http://www.linode.com/index.cfm) or [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

Shared hosting services generally don't allow you to install your own services, so you'll have to use what they provide for you. Most provide an RDBMS, like MySQL, but there aren't many providing MongoDB for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in because I was wondering the same thing and came across this when I searched skynet, [mLab](https://mlab.com/). They have standard pricing for hosting a mongoDB setup and deployment as well as a free version for dev work.